# A formula that defines constructible universe

Tags: logic, set-theory

> \begin{multline}
> \mathrm{Def}(X) := 
> \Bigl\{ \{y \mid y\in X \text{ and } \Phi(y,z_1,\ldots,z_n) \text{ is true in }(X,\in) \} \mid \\
> \Phi \text{ is a first order formula and } z_1,\ldots,z_n\in X\Bigr\}.
> \end{multline}
>
> ([Constructible Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe), Wikipedia)

I saw somewhere at stackexchange that $\Phi$ can be defined, but was not able to find it. So, is there anyway to define what such $\Phi$ would be?

Comment: Have you tried to open a *book*? Wikipedia is a good place to get an overview about things, but not to study. This site is not a supplement for trying to figure things on your own after working through the first part of Jech's *Set Theory*, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Note that given a (first-order) formula $\Phi$ of set theory (with free variables among $u, v_1 , \ldots , v_n$) and $a_1 , \ldots , a_n \in X$ we can define the set $\{ y \in X : ( X , \in ) \models \Phi [ y, a_1 , \ldots , a_n ] \}$.  The family $\mathrm{Def}(X)$ of all sets "definable" over $X$ is then the collection of all such sets as $\Phi$ varies over all formulas and $a_1 , \ldots , a_n$ vary over all elements of $X$.

There *is* a formula $\psi (x)$ such that a set $a$ is constructible iff $\psi[a]$ holds (and so $\mathbf{L} = \{ x : \psi[x] \}$).  A common abbreviation for this formula is $( \exists \alpha \in \mathbf{Ord}) ( x \in L_\alpha )$, and I understand if this is not too helpful.  For more detail please consult some of the following references:

1. Jech, *Set Theory: Third Millennium Edition*, pp.175-188.
2. Drake, *Set Theory: An Introduction to Large Cardinals*, pp.127-134.
3. Kunen, *Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs*, pp.165-173.

---

For some (minimal) details.

You can fix to a Gödel numbering of the formulas of set theory, and say that a set $Y$ is "definable" over $X$ iff for some $n \in \omega$ and parameters $a_1 , \ldots , a_n \in X$ (where $n$ is determined by $n$) $Y$ is the set of all $y \in X$ such that the structure $( X , \in )$ "thinks" that the $n$th formula with the parameters $y, a_1 , \ldots , a_n$ is true. This step is definable, though perhaps tedious to set up.

Another option is to go via so-called [Gödel operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_operation), and show that for a transitive $X$, $\operatorname{Def}(X)$ is just the closure of $X \cup \{ X \}$ under these operations (restricted to the power set of $X$). Each of these operations is definable (recursive, even), and from there it is pretty straightforward to define the closure (by recusion up to $\omega$).

Comment: So, we needn't to quantify over $\Phi$? (I knew this operation is illegal inside a model.)

Comment: @MinghuiOuyang Correct. There are at least a couple of ways of accomplishing this, and I've sketched a bit more in my answer above.

Comment: I saw in Jech's book he used the second method you mentioned and I understood it. But I still doubting about the first method you said (I'm not familiar with Gödel numbering). According to Gödel numbering, do you mean we can emulate formulas in the language by elements in $\omega$ which is **inside** a model? This means we could quantify over **formulas**! In this way, what's the difference between higher-order logic and predicate logic?

Comment: @MinghuiOuyang The set Def($X$) is not defined within $X$, but from the outside. $X$ is a *set* in the universe of set-theory $V$. In $V$ you can definitely quantify over the formulas - they are simple objects defined recursively.  The problem is to have a *satisfaction relation* for all formulas, which you can't have from within the model $(X,\in)$, but $V$ does have a satisfaction relation for $X$, i.e in $V$ one can define the notion $(X,\in) \vDash \phi$ for every formula, and since these are all sets, you can also (in $V$!) quantify over the formulas.